# Solubility of alkali and alkaline earth metal carbonates

Tags: solubility, alkali-metals, alkaline-earth-metals

The solubility of alkali metal carbonates increase down the group, while those of alkaline earth metals decrease down the group.

We can explain the decrease in solubility of alkaline earth metal carbonates by stating that their lattice enthalpies remain somewhat the same due to the larger size of the carbonate anion, and the hydration enthalpies of the metals keep decreasing down the group.

If we were to apply the same principle to the carbonates of alkali metals, the order would be opposite to what is actually observed. Why is it that the solubility of alkali metal carbonates increase down the group ? What makes them show a different trend than the alkaline earth metal carbonates ?